# Why doesn't the 'follow' button on django work?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm using Django 2.2 and PostgreSql. I'm trying to create a simple app that I want to follow neighboring users. 'Follow' button will increase the number of followed, 'Unfollow' button will decrease the number of followed. However, the 'Follow' button does not work. How can I solve this problem?

following/models.py

```
class Following(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fallower', null=True)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='fallowing')
```

following/views.py

```
def user_follow_unfollow(request):
    response = sub_user_follow_unfollow(request)
    data = response.get('data')
    followed = response.get('followed')
    numbers_followed_and_follower= Following.user_followed_and_follower(followed)
    context = {'user': followed, 'followers': numbers_followed_and_follower['followers'],
           'followeds': numbers_followed_and_follower['followeds']}
    html = render_to_string('following/following_partion.html', context=context, request=request)
    data.update({'html': html})
    return JsonResponse(data=data)

def sub_user_follow_unfollow(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()

    data = {'follow status': True, 'html': '', 'is_valid': True, 'msg': '<b>Unfollow</b>'}
    follower_username = request.GET.get('follower_username', None)
    followed_username = request.GET.get('followed_username', None)

    follower = get_object_or_404(User, username=follower_username)
    followed = get_object_or_404(User, username=followed_username)

    does_follow_the_user= Following.user_does_follow_the_user(follower=follower, followed=followed)

    if not does_follow_the_user:
        Following.user_follow(follower=follower, followed=followed)
    else:
        Following.user_unfollow(followed=followed, follower=follower)
        data.update({'msg': '<b>Follow</b>', 'follow_status': False})
    return {'data': data, 'followed': followed}
```

templates.following_partion.html

```
      {% if request.neighbor_detail != user %}
          <div>
              <button followed='{{ neighbor_detail.username }}' followed='{{ request.neighbor_detail.username }}'
                      url="{% url 'following:user_follow_and_unfollow' %}" id="follow_unfollow_button"
                      class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
                  {% if does_follow_the_user%}
                      <b>Unfollow</b>
                  {% else %}
                      <b>Follow</b>
                  {% endif %}
              </button>
          </div>
      {% endif %}


   <div class="followers col-lg-offset-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-3 text-center">
<span><b>followers</b></span>
<button url="{% url 'following:fallowed-or-fallowers-list' 'fallowers' %}" follow_type="followers"
        username="{{ neighbor_detail.username }}" class="follow_button btn-block btn btn-primary">
    {{ followers}}
</button>
```

```
  <div class="followeds col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-center">
<span><b>Followeds</b></span>
<button url="{% url 'following:followed-or-followers-list' 'followed' %}" follow_type="followed"
        username="{{ neighbor_detail.username }}" class="follow_button btn-block btn btn-success">
    {{ followeds}}
</button>
```

my script

```
 <script>
 $("#follow_unfollow_button").click(function () {
               var $this = $(this);
               var $url = $this.attr('url');
               var $takip_eden = $this.attr('follower');
               var $takip_edilen = $this.attr('followed');
               var data = {follower_username: $follower, followed_username: $followed};
               $.ajax({
                   url: $url,
                   type: 'GET',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: data,
                   success: function (data) {
                       if (data.is_valid) {
                           $this.html(data.msg);
                           $("#user_following").html(data.html)
                       }
                   }
               })
           });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you create a `Following` model rather than adding a Many-to-many relationship between users `followers=models.ManyToManyField(...)`? That would make the python code much easier to read, it's very difficult now to understand.

Comment: In addition: you're not showing us the code for `sub_user_follow_unfollow(request)` nor for `Following.user_followed_and_follower(followed)` which looks like it's the crucial bit of code here. And finally, you're changing data in the database when following/unfollowing (I assume) so your AJAX call should be a POST not a GET.

Comment: I tried with `followers = models.ManyToManyField (...) `but failed. This was the reference sample I found. If you know, can you give me another example?

Comment: The M2M and POST suggestions are just suggestions, they are not the reason why your code isn't working. They would just improve it. See my answer for steps to take to debug.

Comment: I added the view of `sub_user_follow_unfollow`

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you as there's too many missing pieces. However, this should not be too difficult to debug, here are some things you should inspect:

1. In your browser developer tools, inspect the HTTP request (XHR request). What parameters are being sent?
2. In your python debugger, inspect the values of `request.GET`, `data`, `numbers_followed_and_follower`. If you don't know these, it's impossible to tell what's wrong.
3. If it's still not clear what's wrong, in your python IDE, set a breakpoint in your view and step through your code line by line, inspecting the results. I cannot stress how important it is to use an IDE with a proper debugger.
4. In your browser developer tools, inspect the HTTP response to your AJAX request. What is being returned?

You need to analyse step-by-step your various variables to understand where's the issue.

**Suggestions**

- You should really use POST (not GET) in your AJAX call, since you're modifying the database.
- Use a `ManyToManyField` to register followers. They are just a relationship between two users:

  ```
  follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, related_name="followers")
  ```

  By specifying `symmetrical=False` you tell  Django to distinguish the two directions of the relationship. In order to create or remove the relationship in your view, and to view relationships, you can just:

  ```
  user.follows.add(other_user)  # user follows other_user
  user.follows.remove(other_user)  # user unfollows other_user
  user.followers.all()  # people following
  user.followers.count()  # number of followers
  ```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: ManyToManyDescriptor object has no attribute add 'I get this error. Do you have any idea about the solution?

Comment: That happens when doing what? Sounds like you're trying to add a relationship the other way round: `user.followers.add(other_user)`. You can't do that. Just do then `other_user.follows.add(user)`. Or maybe you're doing this on the class instead of the user instance: `User.follows.add(...)` would throw this error.

Comment: This is where I get the neighbors' details. I think I should add it here.`def neighbor_detail(request,username):
    neighbor_detail = get_object_or_404(User,username = username)
    neighbor_list = StoreOtherInfo.objects.all()
    product_list = Product.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'store/neighbor_detail.html', {'neighbor_detail':neighbor_detail, 'neighbor_list':neighbor_list, 'product_list':product_list'})`